# Reading integers from file using Python

Tags: python, file, integer

I´ve a "binary" file with variable size record. Each record is composed of an amount of little endians 2 byte-sized integer numbers. I know the start position of each record and it´s size.

What´s the fastest way to read this to a Python array of integer?

Comment: See `struct.unpack()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: please, don't shorten the verb 'have' in simple tenses

Comment: @AndrewLavq Wow!, is that an SO recommendation.  The OP might not be speaking American English, and other cultures use that idiom

Comment: @AndrewLavq: [This has been covered](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8); by British usage, "I've a something" is legit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do better than opening the file and reading the size of each recorde then use `struct.unpack('<i', buff)` for each integer you want to read, `file.read(2)`, will get you 2 integers.